# Is there a way to use the Terraform Cloud API to store and retrieve secrets in Python scripts?

Tags: python, terraform, terraform-cloud

I have a requirement to store my secret in terraform cloud and read it via python client. I am looking for any example to do it.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/api-docs/ I have gone through this API and tried to investigate where can I put secret-key and retrieve secret-value.

Comment: Have you any code that you can provide - show where the issue is?